# How to run trained Tensorflow model on webcam in Java

Tags: java, macos, tensorflow

I have trained my Tensorflow object detection model for a single class only.

I have followed [this tutorial](http:////github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10/tree/d1c5b59803543e48362c27c48d704d4b0d92d135) to train the model.

This tutorial produces a .pb file. I want to use it on a live webcam. I have trained the model on Mac, and want to use it on a webcam (live stream) in Java.
Can anyone tell me how I can do this?